Motion word problem
Two cyclists depart from two different locations A and B at the same time. They cycle towards each other at constant speed (km/min) and meet after time t. If the first cyclist's speed was twice as big, they would have met 5 minutes earlier. If the second cyclist's speed was twice as big, they would have met 8 minutes earlier. Find the value of t.
The system of equations can be written as:
$$\begin{cases}
(v_1+v_2)t=s \\ 
(2v_1+v_2)(t-5)=s \\ 
(v_1+2v_2)(t-8)=s
\end{cases}
$$
Where $v_1,{v_2}$ and $s$ are the first cyclist's speed, second cyclist's speed and the distance between A and B respectively.
Substituting s from equation 1 into equations 2 and 3 we get:
$$\begin{cases}
(2v_1+v_2)(t-5)=(v_1+v_2)t \\ 
(v_1+2v_2)(t-8)=(v_1+v_2)t
\end{cases}
$$
I've learned to solve these types of equations through trial and error but still lack a grasp on what exactly is happening. I realise that this system has more variables than equations so it can't be fully solved but we can still get a value for t as follows:
Find the ratio $\frac{v_1}{v_2}$ in both equations. We get:
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{v_1}{v_2}=\frac{5}{t-10} \\ 
\frac{v_1}{v_2}=\frac{t-16}{8}
\end{cases}
$$
Then by setting the right hand sides of both euqations to be equal:
$$\frac{5}{t-10}=\frac{t-16}{8}$$
We get the answer $t=20$
My qeustion is, is there some intuitive way to understand what exactly is the purpose of finding the ratios of speeds in order to solve for t in this system of equations. So far all the tutorials I've seen only show what steps to do without much explanation of what their purpose is.

While it seems like there are three equations and four variables initially, there are actually only three variables. This is because scaling $s$ and $v_i$’s doesn’t affect the problem at all (provided you don’t scale them to $0$). So the “true” variables are $t$, $s/v_1$, and $s/v_2$. Equivalently, you can set $s=1$ at the beginning without affecting anything.

@Pranay Is there any literature for further reading? I do realise that the actual distance here is irrelevant as long as you scale the speeds appropriately.

I have never seen such literature.  Further, since the problem is pre-calculus (i.e. algebra only), you would not expect a math professor to write such a book, since it would not help their career.  So, the best that you can hope for is to develop instincts based on exposure to many such isolated problems from diverse recreational math sources.  Beyond that, I think that your instincts were spot on.  That is, first you converted the constraints into equations, making no assumptions.  Then, only after you had observed that you have 3 equations in 4 unknowns, did you get creative.
